# Joomla 3.0 installation on localhost using xampp stuck on configuration step

Tags: php, joomla, installation, localhost

Jooma 3.0 is stuck on its first step of installation which is configuration. I am installing it locally using xampp. I have tried two things for it:

1. Run the xampp as admin
2. changed `session.use_cookies=1` in "php.ini"

Can anyone help me in sorting out this issue?

Comment: Ensure you're using the latest version of Xampp. You should also use Joomla 3.1.5

Answer (score 3):

thats how i solved this

open libraries/joomla/filter/input.php
replace following

```
$source = preg_replace('/&#(\d+);/me', "utf8_encode(chr(\\1))", $source); // decimal notation
$source = preg_replace('/&#x([a-f0-9]+);/mei', "utf8_encode(chr(0x\\1))", $source); // hex notation
```

with this in input.php

```
$source = preg_replace_callback('/&#x(\d+);/mi', function($m){return utf8_encode(chr('0x'.$m[1]));}, $source); // decimal notation
$source = preg_replace_callback('/&#x([a-f0-9]+);/mi', function($m){return utf8_encode(chr('0x'.$m[1]));}, $source); // hex notation
```

Comment: Exactly, this will fix the issue. PLease check this other post for more feedback:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18856907/unable-to-install-joomla-in-localhost

Answer (score 1):

What error are you getting? What did you put in the **Admin Email** textbox? Just type **admin@localhost.com**  in that textbox. Check the other fields also especially the **Confirm Admin Password** . Provide some more details so that it is easier to understand your problem and help you.

Comment: Site name=asif ; Description="here is nothing"; email="admin@localhost.com"; admin="admin"; password="admin";  confirm password="admin"; setoffline="yes"........Still blue progress bar is running and process got stuck on this point.

Comment: set offline to **No** and try. Or, better still download the .tar.bz2 joomla file and extract with 7zip and then extract the .tar file directly into htdocs using 7zip. Sometimes, extraction methods also prevent proper installation.

Comment: i have tried the suggestions,u have provided me.BUt its not working at all.

Comment: file permission should be  full control and older version of xampp worked for me.Thanks CodeCruncher for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `wamp\www\Your joomla folder\installation\sql\mysql` and open `Joomla.sql`. Find the term `ENGINE=InnoDB` and replace all with `ENGINE=MyIsam`. MyIsam is more supported and compatible with Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

If you getting error installing joomla 3.0 using xampp 1.7.3 then you should move to xampp 1.8.1, because php version in xampp 1.7.3 is 5.3.1 and joomla 3.0.3 needs php version 5.4.

So, you either move to xampp 1.8.1 or try wamp 2.2 e. This will solve your problem.