# Unable to install joomla in localhost

Tags: php, joomla, localhost, joomla3.0

today i was trying to install joomla on localhost but with web installer after filling configuration info when i click next nothing happens but just an processing image is displayed as shown in image
[image]I tried with different browsers but same problem is everywhere,I have left it for 15-20 minutes ,restarted server/laptop yet same problem.I knew there is no problem with installation source as I have already installed it before.
Well I am using EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC11 Please help!!
I have wordpress installed in my computer and it have no issues..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joomla 3.1.5 have bug with PHP 5.5 but you do not need to worry to make it work you just need to modify an file `input.php` file located in `libraries/joomla/filter/input.php`
here you go:
open input.php with your favorite text editor
find and replace

```
$source = preg_replace('/&#(\d+);/me', "utf8_encode(chr(\\1))", $source); // decimal notation
```

with

```
$source = preg_replace_callback('/&#(\d+);/m', function($m){return utf8_encode(chr($m[1]));}, $source); // decimal notation
```

And

```
$source = preg_replace('/&#x([a-f0-9]+);/mei', "utf8_encode(chr(0x\\1))", $source); // hex notation
```

with

```
$source = preg_replace_callback('/&#x([a-f0-9]+);/mi', function($m){return utf8_encode(chr('0x'.$m[1]));}, $source); // hex notation
```

or for your continence I have uploaded an fixed input.php file you can download it [here](http://bit.ly/1dVatpq) just replace input.php with original one and you are done..!!

Comment: Yes to fix its bugs and make it compactiable

Comment: Joomla doesn't support PHP 5.5 yet. I fully disagree with your answer as you're editing a core library file. This should **NOT** be done. Changes may get overridden in a Joomla update and they may cause problem with other functions. You have provided a dirty fix and haven't even tested to see if it has any bad affects. If it were up to me, I would remove this answer

Comment: This editing is preferred by experts and not by me check it out at https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/1309/files and you should never fear of doing exoeriments on anything unless you know what are you doing
espically when you are doing it on localhost(according to question)

Answer (score 2):

Joomla 3.x doesn't support PHP 5.5 which is what EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC11 uses. You need to downgrade to an EasyPHP-DevServer version that uses PHP 5.4 or 5.3, the choice is up to you.

Comment: Considering there was an unfixed bug in J3 fixed by accepting the fix mentioned by @subhanker you can use php 5.5 with Joomla now!